# Blank cells showing up as zero in Excel in data label for bar chart

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010, charts

I have a chart with bar and line graphs on it. The idea of this graph is to auto-update monthly, so I don't want to manually manipulate this graph at all.  I figured out how to ignore blank cells via `=NA()` for the line graphs, but that doesn't work for the bar graph.

How can I get the bar graph to ignore blank values, instead of automatically calling them zero? The problem is I can't ignore all zeros because zero can be a real result. I need to ignore blank cells only.

[image: data screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

Right click the chart and choose "Select Data"

Click "Hidden and Empty Cells"

-or-

[First eliminate blanks from the list](http://www.tushar-mehta.com/excel/newsgroups/dynamic_charts/)

[Then plot a chart using dynamic ranges](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/noblanks.htm)